# Tomcat App Deployemnt Issue

Tags: java, apache, jsp, web, tomcat7

I have managed to deploy a working app on local host using

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdminLogout",urlPatterns = "/Dashboard/AdminLogout")
```

But when I upload the war file to my server which has both Apache and Tomcat running it seem to work until I make a post to a servelet where it give a 404

so what i did was I used the url as

```
www.example.com:8080
```

Which works again until i do a post request to a servelet .

I thought it maybe a issue with the annotation so I defined my Servelets on my web.xml.

But still it didn't seem to do anything .

I found out when both Apache and Tomcat run Tomcat listens to the port 8080 and 8009

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue ! It was because Apache was not forwarding the request properly to Tomcat .When Apache doesn't run Tomcat seems to work fine .